Cannot get planning scene when planning motion with Interbotix WX250s using MoveIt!
I aim at planning motion with a physical Interbotix Widow-X250s robotic arm. I work with ROS2 on a Raspberry Pi 5 operated by Ubuntu 22.04.
I launch xsarm_moveit.launch.py as indicated in the constructor's tutorial. Unfortunately, the Planning Scene cannot be loaded in the RViz station (message "Planning Scene : Requested initial scene failed" as seen in the screenshot below). Moreover, the actual pose of the arm is not shown in the station.

In the terminal, the logs reveal several problems, particularly in defining the Move Group node and the Controller Manager (below are shown only errors and warnings) :
...
[ros2_control_node-3] [WARN] [1719998304.136143470] [wx250s.controller_manager]: [Deprecated] Passing the robot description parameter directly to the control_manager node is deprecated. Use '~/robot_description' topic from 'robot_state_publisher' instead.
...
[move_group-1] [WARN] [1719998304.412076777] [move_group]: Falling back to using the the move_group node namespace (deprecated behavior).
...
[move_group-1] [WARN] [1719998304.681879453] [move_group.moveit.occupancy_map_monitor]: Resolution not specified for Octomap. Assuming resolution = 0.1 instead
[move_group-1] [ERROR] [1719998304.682057141] [move_group.moveit.occupancy_map_monitor]: No 3D sensor plugin(s) defined for octomap updates
...
[xs_sdk-6] [WARN] Writing startup register values to EEPROM. This only needs to be done once on a robot if using a default motor config file, or after a motor config file has been modified. Can set `write_eeprom_on_startup` to false from now on.
...
[ros2_control_node-3] [WARN] [1719998305.831259985] [wx250s.controller_manager]: Could not enable FIFO RT scheduling policy. Consider setting up your user to do FIFO RT scheduling. See [https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control/controller_manager/doc/userdoc.html] for details.
...
[ERROR] [move_group-1]: process has died [pid 2362, exit code -6, cmd '/opt/ros/rolling/lib/moveit_ros_move_group/move_group --ros-args --params-file /tmp/launch_params_9lqzprnd --params-file /tmp/launch_params_wd4_om_4 --params-file /tmp/launch_params_pzl7ywkr --params-file /home/pi/interbotix_ws/install/interbotix_xsarm_moveit/share/interbotix_xsarm_moveit/config/kinematics.yaml --params-file /tmp/launch_params_mii5ilpp --params-file /tmp/launch_params_36u4nvtl --params-file /tmp/launch_params_0rye57qp --params-file /tmp/launch_params_9ptj3j7j --params-file /tmp/launch_params_yw1yqwn5 -r wx250s/get_planning_scene:=/wx250s/get_planning_scene -r /arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory:=/wx250s/arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory -r /gripper_controller/follow_joint_trajectory:=/wx250s/gripper_controller/follow_joint_trajectory'].

However, the joint states are visible to ROS, I checked it using ros2 topic echo /wx250s/joint_states in the terminal. It returns consistent data.
The planning scene also seems to get data, I checked it using ros2 topic echo /monitored_planning_scene in the terminal. It returns :
name: (noname)+
robot_state:
  joint_state:
    header:
      stamp:
        sec: 0
        nanosec: 0
      frame_id: world
    name:
    - waist
    - shoulder
    - elbow
    - forearm_roll
    - wrist_angle
    - wrist_rotate
    - gripper
    - left_finger
    - right_finger
    position:
    - 0.0
    - 0.0
    - 0.0
    - 0.0
    - 0.0
    - 0.0
    - 0.0
    - 0.026
    - -0.026
    velocity: []
    effort: []
  multi_dof_joint_state:
    header:
      stamp:
        sec: 0
        nanosec: 0
      frame_id: world
    joint_names: []
    transforms: []
    twist: []
    wrench: []
  attached_collision_objects: []
  is_diff: false
robot_model_name: wx250s
fixed_frame_transforms:
- header:
    stamp:
      sec: 0
      nanosec: 0
    frame_id: world
  child_frame_id: world
  transform:
    translation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    rotation:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
allowed_collision_matrix:
  entry_names:
  - wx250s/base_link
  - wx250s/gripper_bar_link
  - wx250s/gripper_link
  - wx250s/gripper_prop_link
  - wx250s/left_finger_link
  - wx250s/lower_forearm_link
  - wx250s/right_finger_link
  - wx250s/shoulder_link
  - wx250s/upper_arm_link
  - wx250s/upper_forearm_link
  - wx250s/wrist_link
  entry_values:
  - enabled:
    - false
    - false
    - false
    - false
    - false
    - false
    - false
    - true
    - false
    - false
    - false
  - enabled:
    - false
    - false
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - false
    - false
    - true
    - true
  - enabled:
    - false
    - true
    - false
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - false
    - false
    - true
    - true
  - enabled:
    - false
    - true
    - true
    - false
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - false
    - false
    - true
    - true
  - enabled:
    - false
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - false
    - true
    - true
    - false
    - false
    - true
    - true
  - enabled:
    - false
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - false
    - true
    - false
    - false
    - true
    - true
  - enabled:
    - false
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - false
    - false
    - false
    - true
    - true
  - enabled:
    - true
    - false
    - false
    - false
    - false
    - false
    - false
    - false
    - true
    - true
    - false
  - enabled:
    - false
    - false
    - false
    - false
    - false
    - false
    - false
    - true
    - false
    - true
    - false
  - enabled:
    - false
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - false
    - true
  - enabled:
    - false
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - true
    - false
    - false
    - true
    - false
  default_entry_names: []
  default_entry_values: []
link_padding:
- link_name: wx250s/base_link
  padding: 0.0
- link_name: wx250s/gripper_bar_link
  padding: 0.0
- link_name: wx250s/gripper_link
  padding: 0.0
- link_name: wx250s/gripper_prop_link
  padding: 0.0
- link_name: wx250s/left_finger_link
  padding: 0.0
- link_name: wx250s/lower_forearm_link
  padding: 0.0
- link_name: wx250s/right_finger_link
  padding: 0.0
- link_name: wx250s/shoulder_link
  padding: 0.0
- link_name: wx250s/upper_arm_link
  padding: 0.0
- link_name: wx250s/upper_forearm_link
  padding: 0.0
- link_name: wx250s/wrist_link
  padding: 0.0
link_scale:
- link_name: wx250s/base_link
  scale: 1.0
- link_name: wx250s/gripper_bar_link
  scale: 1.0
- link_name: wx250s/gripper_link
  scale: 1.0
- link_name: wx250s/gripper_prop_link
  scale: 1.0
- link_name: wx250s/left_finger_link
  scale: 1.0
- link_name: wx250s/lower_forearm_link
  scale: 1.0
- link_name: wx250s/right_finger_link
  scale: 1.0
- link_name: wx250s/shoulder_link
  scale: 1.0
- link_name: wx250s/upper_arm_link
  scale: 1.0
- link_name: wx250s/upper_forearm_link
  scale: 1.0
- link_name: wx250s/wrist_link
  scale: 1.0
object_colors: []
world:
  collision_objects: []
  octomap:
    header:
      stamp:
        sec: 0
        nanosec: 0
      frame_id: world
    origin:
      position:
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.0
      orientation:
        x: 0.0
        y: 0.0
        z: 0.0
        w: 1.0
    octomap:
      header:
        stamp:
          sec: 0
          nanosec: 0
        frame_id: ''
      binary: false
      id: ''
      resolution: 0.0
      data: []
is_diff: false
---

Do you know what could be the reason for the bug?

Move group node wrongly defined in the .launch?

Controller configuration wrongly defined in the .launch?

Something abnormal in the data provided to the planning scene?

Something else?


